# A plugin that makes eclipse usable documentation editor

Tags: eclipse

I'm looking for a plugin that will make Eclipse a decent documentation editor with outlining, images etc... Does anyone know about anything? I've tried NQDoc, which is quite good but doesn't support vim plugin.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no direct experience with this tools, but the [Eclipse MarketPlace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/) is a good place to list all available solutions.

For instance: [all **Documentations** tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/taxonomy/term/5).